# Build a bijection $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}\setminus[0,1].$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Build a bijection $f: \mathbb{Q} \to  \mathbb{Q}\setminus[0,1].$

What about $f(x)=x+1$ if $x>0$  and $f(x)=x-1$  for $x<0?$

Comment: With the second part of your definition, how do you reach $-\frac12$?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $\geq 1$ and $\leq 0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reduce the problem into two steps:

1. find a bijection between $\mathbb Q $ and $\mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$
2. find a bijection between $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb Q \setminus [0,1]$

The first one can be achieved by some sort of *shift*... of course you know how to find a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$ (here I assume $0\in \mathbb N$). The second one is very easy... define it piecewise.

Compose the two bijection to solve your problem.